# Getting text from HTML with class tag

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to extract the 3/14/2017 from the following HTML code:

```
<div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnPostDateCell">
<table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="divListTableBodyLabel">3/14/2017</div>
```

I am using Excel VBA to do so and have the following code to try to test the information that I am pulling:

```
Sub CC()
Dim ie As Object
marker = 0
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "Main" & "*" Then 
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next


extract1 = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel")(3).innerText

MsgBox extract1
```

There are multiple instances of divListTableBodyLabel on the page with various dates, so I am just seeing if I can get any of them to appear and then I can worry about getting the exact one I want. I have tried all of the id's or class names above and nothing returns?

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to load completely - Such as `Do While IE.Busy or IE.ReadyState <> 4` `DoEvents` `Loop`? Also, instead of `.InnerText`, try `.Value` and see if that gets what you need. Other suggestion would be to remove the `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get an error message, and report back here with it.

Comment: Also, I would make it a habit of using `Option Explicit` in your code. I don't see where you declared `objShell` or a few other variables. This can help cut down on errors quite a bit.

Comment: Have you tried  using the Id  or possibly looping through  the elements using  `For each` `ie.document.getElementById("tdColumnPostDateCell").getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel")(0).innerText`

Comment: @Mitch I tried the `.Value` and didn't get anything either. I also don't think it's an issue with grabbing the correct IE instance because I've tested this same code on another page and it returns what I am looking for. I think I'm not able to grab the correct HTML portion for wahtever reason. I tried the following as @Mitch suggested but I am getting an error: `For Each oElement In ie.document.getElementById("tdColumnPostDateCell").getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel")` I've declared oElement as an Object.

Comment: Try `For Each oElement In ie.document.getElementById("tdColumnPostDateCell")` Then use `MsgBox "This element is  " & oElement` and see what it tells you. If you can find the right one, it may just be an issue of which index number it is.

Comment: Maybe that should be `oElement.innerText` instead of just `oElement`

Comment: So the webpage seems like it was the issue. It's hard to describe but it seems like there were two pages open on the same webpage and the text I was trying to extract resided on the "second page." If I went to that "second page" directly, then my code worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Someone here gave me the following code to set an IE object, and it works fantastically.

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim RetVal As Object

    Set RetVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        'check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        'assign it to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like "*" & sLocation & "*" Then
            Set RetVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = RetVal

End Function
```

So just `Set IE = GetIE("www.google.com")` and you are good to go. See if this helps any.